# Return table in function postgres

Tags: postgresql, function, stored-procedures

When trying to return table in postgres, this my query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION list_log_approval(IN p_create_code INTEGER,IN p_update_code INTEGER) RETURNS
TABLE(processcode integer, processname VARCHAR,id BIGINT, pleader CHARACTER VARYING,activity VARCHAR,date_plead timestamp)
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$ 
BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM log_approval WHERE processcode = $1 and status = 'A' or status = 'D')AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM log_approval WHERE processcode = $2 and status = 'A' or status = 'D') THEN
                RETURN QUERY SELECT * from vw_list_appv;
        END IF;
    RETURN;
END $$;
```

-- i call like this

```
select * from list_log_approval(1070,1072)
```

I get the following error:

> [Err] ERROR:  column reference "processcode" is ambiguous
>   LINE 3:   processcode**

why is it ambiguous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`processcode` is used both as function parameter and as table column.

The best thing is to use function parameters with a different name, like `p_processcode`.

But you can also disambiguate by qualifying the name: `log_approval.processcode` for the column and `list_log_approval.processcode` for the function parameter.